# Calculating exponential moving average across millions of rows

Tags: c#, mysql

I am calculating the moving average for 5,534,446 rows in one table. I am using C# as my language and MySQL as the database. Below is the code I am using to gather and calculate an exponential moving average for different sets of days. The program is working perfectly but it is taking forever to calculate the values one at a time. Since I am new to programming, I figure this could be three times more efficient. What can I do to improve this program's speed?

```
private void CalculateMovingAverage()
        {
            l.CreateRunningEntry(3, "CalculateMovingAverage", "Beginning to calulate exponential moving averages for companies.");
            conn.ConnectionString = r.getMysqlConnection();

            //This is the list for the type of exponential averages we want to calculate
            decimal[] movingDays = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 100, 200 };

            //Go through each type of day moving average so that we calculate for each one
            foreach (decimal avgDayLimit in movingDays)
            {
                //We'll go ahead and calculate the smoothing constant for each moving average type
                decimal multiplier = CalcEMAMultiplier(avgDayLimit);

                //Run a query to get all of the companies with the required number of records in the hitorical_data table
                List<string> symbolList = CompaniesWithHistoricalDays(conn, avgDayLimit);

                //For each symbol, we need to make sure we have a simple moving average to start out with
                foreach (string companySymbol in symbolList)
                {
                    //Check if there are any existing records in the moving average table
                    bool maExists = DoesMovingAverageExist(conn, avgDayLimit, companySymbol);

                    //We will need to calculate SMA if there are no records in moving average table
                    if (maExists == false)
                        InsertSMA(conn, avgDayLimit, companySymbol);

                    //Obtain a list of companies where a date exists in historical_datathat does not exist in moving average
                    DateTime maLastDate = LastMovingAverageDate(conn, avgDayLimit, companySymbol);

                    //Pull all of the historic dates and historic closings from dates greater than the one pulled from teh database in the last process
                    List<HistoricalClosing> histDateAndClose = GetHistoricalDateAndClosings(conn, companySymbol, maLastDate);

                    //Insert the calculated EMA into the moving average table
                    foreach (HistoricalClosing close in histDateAndClose)
                        GatherEMAComponents(conn, companySymbol, close.historicDate, close.historicClose, multiplier, avgDayLimit);
                }
            }
        }

    public decimal CalcEMAMultiplier(decimal emaDays)
    {
        decimal emaMultiplier = 2m / (emaDays + 1m);

        return emaMultiplier;
    }

public List<string> CompaniesWithHistoricalDays(MySqlConnection conn, decimal avgDayLimit)
{
    conn.Open();
    l.CreateRunningEntry(3, "CalculateMovingAverage", "Pulling all companies that have maDays = " + avgDayLimit);
    List<string> symbolList = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"select symbol from historical_data group by symbol having count(symbol) >= @maDays;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maDays", avgDayLimit);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 2400;
            using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    symbolList.Add(Convert.ToString(rdr["symbol"]));
                }
                l.CreateRunningEntry(3, "CalculateMovingAverage", "Pulled " + symbolList.Count + " rows.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException mse)
    {
        l.CreateRunningEntry(1, "CalculateMovingAverage", "Error while obtaining companies with historical days equal to or greater than " + avgDayLimit + ". " + mse);
    }
    conn.Close();

    return symbolList;
}

public bool DoesMovingAverageExist(MySqlConnection conn, decimal avgDayLimit, string symbol)
{
    conn.Open();
    string lastDate = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"select ma_date
                                        from moving_average
                                        where ma" + avgDayLimit + @" is not null
                                        and ma_symbol like @symbol
                                        order by ma_date desc limit 1; ";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbol", symbol);
            using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    lastDate = rdr["ma_date"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException sqlException)
    {
        l.CreateRunningEntry(1, "CalculateMovingAverage", "Connection Error at figuring out last moving average date for ma" + avgDayLimit + " and symbol = " + symbol + ". " + sqlException);
    }
    conn.Close();

    if (lastDate == string.Empty)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public void InsertSMA(MySqlConnection conn, decimal avgDayLimit, string companySymbol)
{
    l.CreateRunningEntry(3, "CalculateMovingAverage", "There was no moving average for symbol = " + companySymbol + " and days = " + avgDayLimit);
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"insert into moving_average (ma_symbol, ma_date, ma"+avgDayLimit+ @")
                                select @symbol, max(histDate), avg(histClose)
                                from (select histDate, histClose
                                      from historical_data
                                      where symbol like @symbol
                                      order by histDate asc
                                      limit @avgDayLimit) temp
                                 on duplicate key update ma" + avgDayLimit + @" = values(ma" + avgDayLimit + @");";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbol", companySymbol);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@avgDayLimit", avgDayLimit);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException mse)
    {
        l.CreateRunningEntry(1, "CalculateMovingAverage", "Connection Error at calculating SMA. " + mse);
    }
    conn.Close();
}

public DateTime LastMovingAverageDate(MySqlConnection conn, decimal avgDayLimit, string companySymbol)
{
    DateTime maLastDate = new DateTime();
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"select ma_date
                                from moving_average
                                where ma" + avgDayLimit + @" is not null
                                and ma_symbol like @symbol
                                order by ma_date desc limit 1; ";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbol", companySymbol);
            using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    maLastDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["ma_date"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException mse)
    {
        l.CreateRunningEntry(2, "CalculateMovingAverage", "Connection Error at gathering last moving average date " + mse);
    }
    conn.Close();

    l.CreateRunningEntry(3, "LastMovingAverageDate", "The last date pulled for " + companySymbol + " is " + maLastDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    return maLastDate;
}

public List<HistoricalClosing> GetHistoricalDateAndClosings(MySqlConnection conn, string companySymbol, DateTime maLastDate)
{
    l.CreateRunningEntry(3, "GetHistoricalDateAndClosings", "Getting the list of historical closing data for symbol = " + companySymbol);

    List<HistoricalClosing> historicalClosing = new List<HistoricalClosing>();

    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"select histDate, histClose
                                from historical_data
                                where histDate > @maLastDate
                                and symbol like @symbol
                                order by histDate asc;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maLastDate", maLastDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbol", companySymbol);
            using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    historicalClosing.Add(new HistoricalClosing
                    {
                        historicDate = DateTime.Parse(rdr["histDate"].ToString()),
                        historicClose = decimal.Parse(rdr["histClose"].ToString())
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException mse)
    {
        l.CreateRunningEntry(1, "CalculateMovingAverage", "Connection Error at gathering historical_data list " + mse);
    }
    conn.Close();

    return historicalClosing;
}

public void GatherEMAComponents(MySqlConnection conn, string companySymbol, DateTime historicDate, decimal historicClose, decimal multiplier, decimal avgDayLimit)
{
    l.CreateRunningEntry(4, "GatherEMAComponents", "Gathering all data for EMA.");
    conn.Open();
    decimal lastEMA = new decimal();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"select ma" + avgDayLimit + @" as ema
                                from moving_average
                                where ma_symbol like @symbol
                                and ma" + avgDayLimit + @" is not null
                                order by ma_date desc
                                limit 1; ";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbol", companySymbol);
            using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                    lastEMA = decimal.Parse(rdr["ema"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException sqlException)
    {
        l.CreateRunningEntry(1, "GatherEMAComponents", "Error while gathering last EMA price to calculate EMA for company " + companySymbol + " and maDays = " + avgDayLimit + ". " + sqlException);
    }
    conn.Close();

    decimal exponMovingAvg = CalculateEMA(historicClose, lastEMA, multiplier);

    InsertEMA(conn, companySymbol, historicDate, exponMovingAvg, avgDayLimit);
}

public void InsertEMA(MySqlConnection conn, string companySymbol, DateTime historicDate, decimal exponentialMovingAverage, decimal avgDayLimit)
{
    l.CreateRunningEntry(4, "InsertEMA", "Inserting EMA = " + exponentialMovingAverage + " for company " + companySymbol + " on " + historicDate);
    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = @"insert into moving_average (ma_symbol, ma_date, ma"+avgDayLimit+ @") values (@symbol, @date, @ema) on duplicate key update ma" + avgDayLimit + @" = @ema;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbol", companySymbol);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", historicDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ema", exponentialMovingAverage);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (MySqlException mse)
    {
        l.CreateRunningEntry(1, "InsertEMA", "Error while inserting EMA for company " + companySymbol + ". " + mse);
    }
    conn.Close();
}

public class HistoricalClosing
{
    public DateTime historicDate { get; set; }
    public decimal historicClose { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Probably the best answer is "do it on the Db" but I only use sql server so don't want to hazard a guess at a mysql answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making *many, many* round trips to the database.  Stock information like this isn't very large, typically no more than 252 entries per year (trading days in a year, typically 365 minus holidays), per stock symbol.  I think you would be better off bulk reading all of the data applicable, processing it all in memory, and then doing bulk updates back to the database.

If you have concerns about reading all of that information, you can always break it into chunks, like iterating over symbols instead.  Read all of the data for the first 10, 50, 100 symbols, process and update, then do the same for the next N symbols, etc.

In any case, even though you keep the connection open between queries, you should cut back the number of trips to the database as much as possible (read everything you can, even if it might not be needed), as the overhead of sending the query, executing it, and reading back the results over the network is where your bottleneck is.

Comment: Agreed.  I was thinking far to linear.  But this is only draft number two of this thing. So draft three will be coming up. The other process is running while I work on making it faster. By my calculations I have two weeks to come up with a solution :).